Questions about QED Corrections to Coulomb's law and Electromagnetic Wave Equation
As a disclaimer, this is somewhat similar to this unanswered question, but not entirely.
In standard QED theory, it is frequently demonstrated that the derivation of the Coulomb Potential can be found by equating the Born Approximation with the scattering amplitude between two electrons using only the lowest-order single photon exchange diagram (example here).
One thing I don't understand is why this first order approximation is sufficient for the Coulomb potential and, as it follows, the electromagnetic wave equation.
Of course, one is able to perform higher order corrections to the coulomb potential by the inclusion of higher order diagrams. Notably for example, if you include one of the next highest order diagrams: the two-photon exchange which is associated with the Casimir-Polder potential (see Larry Spruch, Physics Today). We can consider this as the first correction to the Coulomb potential (neglecting self-energy corrections):
$$ V \approx \frac{e^2}{r} + \frac{\hbar e^4}{c^3m^2r^3} $$
Other examples of include the coulomb force with a correction term due to dressing. From this, it seems that you can derive a correction to the electromagnetic wave equation (though I haven't worked this out yet).
Then I think there is a potential paradox to this: the quantized electromagnetic field that is assumed is based on quantizing classical EM wave solutions, not ones with higher order corrections. Is this just a one of many options that one can take? For example, is it possible to described the photon’s field in terms of quantizing a EM wave solution that includes higher order corrections, and just be as valid?
Thank you in advanced.

I don't know what "the photon's field" is supposed to be. Photons are exchanged amounts of energy, momentum and angular momentum. They are not classical charges. Classical fields are emergent phenomena at the level of the mean field theory. They don't exist at the level of the single quantum. The only way we get to mean field theory physically is by averaging over an infinite (very large) number of quanta. That's why measuring a classical Coulomb potential requires a "spacer", i.e. a system that keeps the distance between two charges constant.

@FlatterMann by photon field, I am referring to the quantized electromagnetic field (as in Mandle&Shaw, and 3rd section of wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field). However, in these constructions the classical field equation is the starting point. I'm pointing out that starting with the classical field seems to be an arbitrary choice, and the quantized field could in principle be formulated starting with instead a electromagnetic field based on Maxwell equations derived from higher-order interactions.

Or, I should more carefully say, it is not arbitrary in the sense that starting with the classical field is a useful construction, but I don't understand other than convenience, why it has to necessarily be that way.

While it is customary to "start with the mean field theory", that teaching strategy clouds the ontological issues in quantum mechanics considerably IMHO. Somebody needs to write a modern textbook that first derives the structure of quantum mechanics cleanly from Kolmogorov's axioms (which clarifies the interplay of individual quanta and frequentist averages and the mean field theory) and then deduces quantization of fields by specializing that theoretical framework to Poincare symmetry and (in this case) the electromagnetic field as the mean field theory.
